# Arduino serial RS485 communication: Flush() is a blocking function, alternatives not blocking?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, flush, rs485

I implemented a RS485 communication between Raspberry and Arduino.
First of all, important to know is that it works fine, but I would like to improve the handling.

The issue I'm facing is caused by `Serial.Flush()` function that is helpful to "wait" all bytes are send through serial port but it's blocking! My application is handling a stepper and I can hear a noise every answer Arduino send because, of course, Flush() freezes steps generation for a while.

I found a solution that is "at the limit".. I would like to discuss with you in order to understand if it's good enough or there is something better.

My solution is: based on the baud-rate, I calcolate the time needed to send bytes:

```
usWrite = 1000000*8/baud-rate;  //baud-rate: 9600 -> 833 us
```

Sending the answer:

```
bytesWritten = Serial.print("my answer");
```

then, I'm waiting a number of ms calculated with:

```
if (millis() - timeBeforeWrite >= (bytesWritten*usWrite)/1000) {
  Serial.Flush();
  digitalWrite(PIN_S, LOW);
}
```

As you can see, I'm handing the output to control the MAX485 read/write, so it's critical if I set wrongly the timing.

With this solution the behavior is not so bad, the millis() check help to avoid to block execution for most of the time, Flush() anyhow make the timing correct.
The stepper works better, the noise is reduced a lot. Increasing the time per byte by 1.2 is better again because if you look with oscilloscope, at the end one byte takes 1ms, not 833us as supposed.. however..

Ok, please let me know your opinion, if I can improve somehow.

For example I though to create by hardware the check of serial flow, when no flow of bytes I can toggle the output for MX485, but it's complex.. I prefer something software if possible.

Thanks for any inputs.
Bye
Andrea

Comment: *"one byte takes 1ms, not 833us as supposed"* -- That's because you neglect to account for the framing for each byte, i.e. the start and stop bits.  See https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#2_3

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for detail. I can adjust the formula using 10 instead of 8

Answer (score 1):

If you have to wait for transmit in your code, why not go faster? 9600 is super slow. I run many of my Arduino / Atmel projects at 1M baud if timing is critical.

Also, do you need to calculate a wait time before setting pin_s? serial.flush() should take care of waiting to set that pin.

Finally, digitalWrite is slow. Setting the pin directly would be much faster. like this excerpt from an Arduino mega project:
This part turns the transmit enable and receive enable pins back and
forth on the RS485 chip.

```
  PORTB |= 0x20;                                                                                               // RS485 RE disable
  PORTL |= 0x08;                                                                                               // RS485 DE enable
  Serial3.write(txframe,14);                                                                                   // Send the complete frame over serial port 3 (RS485)
  Serial3.flush();                                                                                             // Wait here until all the bytes are sent
  PORTB &= ~0x20;                                                                                              // RS485 RE enable
  PORTL &= ~0x08;                                                                                              // RS485 DE disable
```

Comment: Yes, 9600 is very slow and I already planned to increase it. The system is home automation for my house and it consists in many small boards, in total I have already 35 nodes. Nothing critical but I started with low speed. As I wrote Serial.flush() is blocking function and the Arduino should handle steps generation for stepper motors and flush freeze it, the motor vibrate. I'm using flush but just to be sure after the time calculated. I will evaluate also the register set instead DigitalWrite, good hint! Thanks. So in conclusion, there is no other way to check Write done not blocking, right?